# Handling save error messages using VBA

Tags: excel, vba

I have the following macro to auto save a workbook:

```
ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs Filename:=Workbooks(2).Path & "\" & ActiveWorkbook.Name
ActiveWorkbook.Close savechanges:=True
```

but the problem I have if the destination folder already has file with this name I get a message from Excel saying that this file already exists and whether I want to replace it.

What I need is the following:

- if user selects `Yes`, then replace the existing file
- if user selects `No` (currently I get a runtime error), then it saves it with V2 at the end of the file name, if this exists then V3 and so on
- if user selects `Cancel`, then they see a message saying *Are you sure you want to cancel*.  If they confirm then it's cancelled, otherwise it returns to the error message.

Or perhaps the code can be edited so that when it `saves as` it checks if file already exists in folder and if it does, then save it as v2.

Comment: You need a separate function whose responsibility will be to come up with a file name. The `Dir$` function will be useful to determine if a file exists, and UX-wise I would advise against having too many confirmation pop-ups, they get annoying for the users.

Comment: As a side note, identifying a workbook by `Workbooks(2)` is dangerous. If they have other workbooks or addins open your code will save something other than what you expect.

Comment: Thanks Doug for your suggestion.  There shouldn't be other books open as they will run macro from one book which will open different books, copy some data from some, vlookup from others and then copy and paste final table into last workbook which has to be saved to the same location as one of the opened workbooks.

Answer (score 1):

You would probably have to refactor your current code to use it 'as-is' - but I think this is the logic that you are looking for:

```
Dim saveName As Variant

retry:

saveName = Application.GetSaveAsFileName

If Not saveName = False Then
    If Len(Dir$(saveName)) = 0 Then
        ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs saveName
    Else
        MsgBox "Workbook already exists, please choose a different name.", vbOkOnly
        GoTo retry:
    End If
Else
    MsgBox "User cancelled save.", vbInformation"
End If
```

Answer (score 0):

Something like

```
If Dir(strfilename) = "" Then
Else
    strfilename=Application.GetSaveAsFilename
End If

ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs strfilename, XlFileFormat.xlOpenXMLWorkbookMacroEnabled
```